# C# inline checked statement does not work

Tags: c#, casting, exception

I have two test methods. The first one works fine. The second one does not throw an exception, but it should. Why doesn't the second one throw a exception?

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
public void LongToInt_OverflowWithCheckedBlock()
{
    checked
    {
        int maxValue = 2147483647;
        long longValue = (maxValue + 1);
        int intValue = (int)longValue;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
public void LongToInt_OverflowWithCheckedStatement()
{

    int maxValue = 2147483647;
    long longValue = (maxValue + 1);
    int intValue = checked((int)longValue);     // No Exception is thrown, why?
}
```

Comment: You have a *late conversion* bug. `longValue = maxValue + 1` does the arithmetic in 32 bit integers *first* and then converts to 64 bit. The most common form of this bug is `double percent = someInteger / 100;`, and the question is then "why is my percentage always zero?"  You have to convert to the type you intend to do the arithmetic in *before* you do the arithmetic, not *after*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason the first one throws and the second one doesn't is because your comparison is a bit off.

- In the 1st method you `check` everything
- In the 2nd method you only `check` the cast from `long` to `int`.

**If you compare them like below they are equal and neither will throw:**

```
private static void MethodA()
{
    int maxValue = 2147483647;
    long longValue = ( maxValue + 1 );
    checked
    {
        int intValue = ( int ) longValue;
    }
}

private static void MethodB()
{
    int maxValue = 2147483647;
    long longValue = ( maxValue + 1 );
    int intValue = checked( ( int ) longValue);
}
```

The reason for this is because this line: `int intValue = checked(( int ) longValue);` isn't the one that's throwing, its this line:

```
long longValue = ( maxValue + 1 );
```

If I put the checked there they will both throw:

```
long longValue = checked( maxValue + 1 );
```

**Why it throws here:**

It throws because `( maxValue + 1 )` is adding 1 to an `int` called `maxValue` (exception occurs here) and **after that** assigning it to a `long`, if you `cast` the `int` to a `long` before doing the adding 1 it will not throw:

```
long longValue = ( (long) maxValue + 1 );
```

Answer (score 9):

**As [MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) said**,

> The ***checked*** keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

The first test method is already checking if there is an overflowing value within the ***declared block***.

[image]

The second test method is only checking the overflowing value ***this line of code only.***

> `int intValue = checked((int)longValue); //Checked expression`

[image]

Since the overflowing is happen before the `checked` expression, the CLR already converted the value.
And the value of that is `-2147483648` [which is legal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) since int range is 
[image]

**What is the difference?**

Test Method 1 : **Checked block**

Test Method 2: **Checked expression**

Answer (score 2):

That's cause you are converting it to `long`. Unchecked `(maxValue + 1)` results in `-2147483648` which you are storing in `long` and in-turn casting back to `int`. Thus after final cast your `intValue` stores `-2147483648`

Instead try like below and it will result in `OverflowException`

```
 int intValue = checked(maxValue + 1);
```

(or) even

```
long longValue = checked((maxValue + 1));
```